# Getting MAX int column but avoiding natural order MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, max

I need to get the biggest folio number record from a services table:

```
services
  - id 
  - folio (int)
```

The folio number is an Int column formed by `year + incremental number`. Every time a record is inserted the folio number is formed by `the_current_year + (max folio found + 1)` Saying that, this is a sample list of available folios:

```
20191
...
2019124
2019125
20201
20202
...
202019
```

As per the sample list, I would have 125 services for year 2019 and 19 services for 2020 so far. Please note that on every year change, the latest digits for the folio number start again from 1.

I'm facing 2 issues here. Treating it as integer and getting the MAX by folio won't work because natural sort order. It will return the biggest int.

So doing:
`SELECT MAX(folio) FROM services LIMIT 1;` returns `2019125` when I actually need to get `202019`

Treating it as varchar won't either work, since it will be ordered by char:
`SELECT MAX(CONVERT(folio, CHAR(50))) FROM services LIMIT 1;` returns `20202` instead of `202019`

So my question is how to get the latest folio number?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want the max folio for each year or just the max folio of all the rows?

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I was expecting for by getting the max folio of all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT folio
FROM services
ORDER BY LEFT(folio, 4) DESC, SUBSTR(folio, 5) + 0 DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

In MySql you can treat integers as strings and apply functions like `LEFT()` and `SUBSTR()`.
By applying `+0` to a string, the string is implicitly converted to a number.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qknfcdJfpiu6jF6omaenaM/0).
Results:

```
| folio  |
| ------ |
| 202019 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off having the year and the serial number in separate columns. You can separate them in the query:

```
SELECT folio
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CAST(substring(folio, 1,4) AS UNSIGNED) as 'year', 
    CAST(substring(folio, 5) AS UNSIGNED) as 'service_no',
    folio
  FROM services
ORDER BY year DESC, service_no DESC
limit 1
) AS q;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kVmYHTovErpXYbKu2Vx33u/2)

Comment: your fiddle is returning `2019125` instead of `202019` so It's not working as expected.

Comment: @Luciano Fiddle fixed